# how do we pass Mat from opencv into tensorflow tf.image.ssim_multiscale?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

I have got some video frames with Opencv Python and able to convert it into grayscale.

Now I want to do something like this to calculate ssim_multiscale

```
    i1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    i2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    i1 = np.array(i1, dtype=np.float64)
    i2 = np.array(i2,dtype=np.float64)
    print(tf.image.ssim_multiscale(i1,i2,255))
```

But I got this error

> shape1 = img1.get_shape().with_rank_at_least(3). 
>   AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_shape'

I have checked the documentation of np.array and it has get_shape attribute. How should I pass Mat into the ssim_multiscale parameter?

```
tf.image.ssim_multiscale(
    img1,
    img2,
    max_val,
    power_factors=_MSSSIM_WEIGHTS
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer

```
while(cap.isOpened()&cap2.isOpened()):
ret, frame = cap.read()
ret2,frame2 = cap2.read()

if ret & ret2:
    a = np.asarray(frame)
    a1=tf.image.convert_image_dtype(a, tf.float32)

    b = np.asarray(frame2)
    b1=tf.image.convert_image_dtype(b, tf.float32)

    test= tf.image.ssim_multiscale(a1,b1,255)
    sess = tf.Session()
    tfssim = sess.run(test)
    print(' tf ms-ssim: '+format(tfssim))
    the_file.write(' tf ms-ssim: '+format(tfssim))
    if(tfssim<1):
        caltfssimnosie+=1
        print(' *tf ms-ssim err')
        the_file.write('  *tf ms-ssim err')
    sess.close
```

if you print the ms-ssim value with print function, it will show weird error